# Ionic list refresh after deleting an item

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying to fetch data asynchronously twitter rest API (fetching my tweets to be more specific), and after I do so, I display them as cards. My problem is when I delete a tweet, it does not reflect in my application.

here's a part of my code:

Twitter service provider.

```
fetchDataFromTwitter() {
    return this.httpReader = this.http.get('url').map((resp) => resp).catch((err: any) => {
      return Observable.of(undefined);
    });
  }
```

twitterList page

```
public dataFromTwitter:any;
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.tweetProvider.fetchDataFromTwitter().subscribe((data: any) => {
    ..
    ..
    ..
 some string manuplation..and iterate threw array of tweets
        this.dataFromTwitter.push({
          screenName:tweet.user.screen_name,
          placeOfId: tweet.full_text.slice(indexStart, indexEnd),
          userId: tweet.full_text.slice(indexStartForToken,indexEndForToken)
        })
      });
}
```

in the view for the twitterList.html page

```
<ion-content padding>
  <div *ngIf="dataFromTwitter">
  <ion-card *ngFor="let data of dataFromTwitter">
    <ion-item>
      <h2 >user: {{data .placeOfId }}</h2>
    </ion-item>
    <p>token: {{data.userId}}</p>
    <ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

the example might have errors but, but I hope the idea is clear.

Answer (score 2):

In order to refresh the list after deleting an item, you could choose any one of the following methods

> 1. On deleting an element, call the get item call again to refresh the list
> 2. Remove(splice) the element from the data source array, this will block the data from showing in the UI.

I will suggest the second one be better.

Comment: hey @Nitheesh the deletion is basically when i delete a tweet on twitter, so how could that linked with my app, and im using splice to get the necessary data from a tweet my app posted

Comment: i also forgot to mention i cannot go with the second option since i must splice the raw data to get the data thats needed

Comment: just for an update, I ended up doing pull on refresh to solve this problem. However, I encountered a method that calls the functions that update the list every N seconds. if anyone is interested in it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one

**Create ion-refresher for your .html files**

```
<ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
<ion-refresher-content pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown" pullingText="Pull to refresh" refreshingSpinner="circles"
  refreshingText="Refreshing...">
</ion-refresher-content>
```

**Create doRefresh() method on .ts**

```
data: any; // contain array of my data

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSampah();
}

async dataSampah() {
  this.session_storage().then(() => {
    this.postPrvdr.getData(`tps/invoice?id_tps=` + this.id_tps).subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res.data;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  });
}

doRefresh(event) {
  this.data = null; // this is replacement of splice
  this.ngOnInit(); // 
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.router.navigate(['/invoice-sampah']);
    event.target.complete();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: this is also can be implements in ionic v4